# Why did my hydrangea's flowers die?

Tags: flowers, hydrangea

I bought these hydrangeas yesterday, today the red one's flowers died and the white one"s don't look as good as yesterday either.
I haven't watered or repoted them yet.

[image][image][image][image][image]

Update: 4 hours after I watered them.
[image]
Thank you for the advices! The red one is coming along also but not as impressively as this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have basically answered your question:

> I haven't watered [...] them yet.

They aren’t dead, they are thirsty! The soil is a bit out of focus in your photos, but it seems very dry. Not all plant sellers will take good care of their stock, especially if you bought them in a grocery store instead of at a florists’. So I recommend you give the pots a good soak, let them drain well and keep your fingers crossed.